# How to find drivers avaliable during selected interval? MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables: drivers and routes. Table drivers consists of driver id, name and surname, and table routes consists of route id, driver id, start time and end time. How do I find out what drivers are available during a selected time interval, for example between 5-25-2020 14:00:00 and 5-29-2020 23:00:00?

I came up with this code, but it gives me the opposite. It shows me name and surname of drivers who already were on a route in given interval

```
select id, name, surname from driver left join route on driver.id=route.driver_id where 5-25-2020 < route.end_time and 5-29-2020 > route.start_time group by 1;
```

EDIT

### driver.id | name | surname

|    1    | name1| surname1

|    2    | name2| surname2

### route.id | route.driver_id | start_time | end_time

|   1    |        1        | 5-25-2020  | 5-29-2020

|   2    |        2        | 5-15-2020  | 5-20-2020

|   3    |        ?        | 5-25-2020  | 5-29-2020

What i am asking is how to select all drivers that are available for the route id 3. Driver 1 is already on the route during that time so the only option is driver id 2. How do i get that driver using sql query?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `5-25-2020 = -2040`...

Comment: i added sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists` to list the drivers that have no planned route that overlaps the target period:

```
select d.*
from drivers d
where not exists (
    select 1
    from routes r
    where   
        r.driver_id = d.driver_id 
        and r.start_time < '2020-05-29 23:00:00'
        and r.end_time   > '2020-05-25 14:00:00'
)
```

Comment: > or swap final argument